# Convert english to Arabic number

Tags: android, unicode

I have a simple mathematical calculation.I need to change the language English into Arabic. I knows about `Unicode` but not sure how can i use it? I just need to display number in Arabic language in Edit Box. I did not want any `setText()` in `edittext` box. because i am not sure that if language is changed, my calculation will be work.